# Artillery - testing an API a several times

Tags: javascript, testing, artillery

I'm trying to use Artillery to test one of my API and resolving a potential bug. Here is my code :

```
  "config": {
    "target": "http://websocket.target",
    "phases": [
      {"duration": 3, "arrivalRate": 4}
    ]
  },
  "scenarios": [
    {
      "name": "target",
      "engine": "socketio",
      "flow": [
        {
          "emit": {
            "namespace": "/test/basket",
            "channel": "add",
            "data": {
              "foodId":91789,
              "restaurantId":3,
            }
          }
        },
        {
         "think":0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I've decided to simulate this situation:

4 users add food to the basket for 3 seconds (without delay). But the most crucial stuff for me is their **concurrency**. Does Artillery have a specific flag or attribute for this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artillery does not provide a way to set a fixed concurrency level. The desired concurrency level can be achieved by having virtual users maintain the connection to the server for some period of time with `think` like in your test script.